# Switch to postgres user on Mac

Tags: postgresql, osx-lion, sudo, su

I would like to `su` to the postgres user on Mac, so that I can run postgres.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
delirium:~ anna$ sudo su postgres
delirium:~ anna$
```

Nothing happens. If I try to run postgres, I then get something like this:

```
delirium:~ anna$ sudo pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l      
/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log startpg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

If I try this in order to `su`, I also get an error:

```
delirium:~ anna$ sudo su - postgres
su: no directory
delirium:~ anna$
```

What can I do instead? I'm fairly sure that the postgres user exists.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That looks consistent with the postgres user not having a login shell. Try `sudo -u postgres bash`

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL is integrated in Server.app available through the App Store in Mountain Lion.

You would have this file:
*/Library/Server/PostgreSQL/Config/org.postgresql.postgres.plist*

**You can sudo to run shell commands as the owner (note the underscore in the username):**

```
sudo -u _postgres createdb the_database -E UTF8
```

**Or connect to the database with all grants:**

```
psql -h localhost -U _postgres postgres
```

Comment: What is the difference between these two commands? Does any have benefit over other?

Comment: The sudo command allows user _postgres more than just connecting to an existing databse, for instance to create a new database.

Comment: With help of `psql` you also will be connected to database as root and will be able to create databases, will not?

Comment: psql is a command that connects to the database, within that scope you can do certain things to manage the database. If you switch to the postgres user, you can run other commands as well under that login account, like make directories, edit files, etc.

Comment: So if I plan to run only SQL it will be enough to `psql -U postgres -c "..."` instead of `sudo -u postgres psql -c "..."`. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, that works.